# More than one key specified in column level FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a database project for my school and I stumble upon this strange issue that I can't seem to solve it. Here is the code i have when trying the create the tables:

```
Create table Offering(
StartDate       DATE            NOT NULL    ,       
PRIMARY KEY(StartDate) 
);

Create table OfferPerWeek(
StartDate       DATE            NOT NULL    ,
StartTime       TIME(0)         NOT NULL    ,
[Day]           VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (StartDate,[Day],StartTime)
FOREIGN KEY (StartDate) 
REFERENCES Offering(StartDate)
);

--The table that have the issues 
Create table OfferPerWeek_Venue(  
[Day]           VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL    ,
StartDate       DATE            NOT NULL    , 
StartTime       TIME(0)         NOT NULL    
PRIMARY KEY (StartDate, [Day], StartTime)
FOREIGN KEY (StartDate, [Day], StartTime) 
REFERENCES OfferPerWeek (StartDate, [Day] , StartTime)
);
```

The error message said that:

> More than one key specified in column level FOREIGN KEY constraint

I am really confused by the problem, I tried to create multiple foreign keys that references to that many primary key of the parent table.

Really hope that this can be fixed, thank you

Comment: That message matches a SQL Server one so I've added that tag. If that's incorrect, please remove that but *add a tag specific to your database system*, as the [tag:sql] tag already told you to do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You are missing commas. Try:

```
Create table OfferPerWeek_Venue(  
[Day]           VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL    ,
StartDate       DATE            NOT NULL    , 
StartTime       TIME(0)         NOT NULL , <-- comma there  
PRIMARY KEY (StartDate, [Day], StartTime), <-- comma there
FOREIGN KEY (StartDate, [Day], StartTime) 
REFERENCES OfferPerWeek (StartDate, [Day] , StartTime)
);
```

You can try the following, naming the foreign key's:

```
Create table OfferPerWeek_Venue(  
[Day]           VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL    ,
StartDate       DATE            NOT NULL    , 
StartTime       TIME(0)         NOT NULL ,  
CONSTRAINT [PK_GoodName] PRIMARY KEY (StartDate, [Day], StartTime), 
CONSTRAINT [FK_GoodName] FOREIGN KEY (StartDate, [Day], StartTime) 
REFERENCES OfferPerWeek (StartDate, [Day] , StartTime)
);
```

Comment: It still does not seem to work for me, let me try to give a full context of the question this time.

Comment: When you say "it still doesn't work", does that mean you get the same error, or a new one?

Answer (score 1):

The `CREATE TABLE` statement is missing a comma before each `CONSTRAINT`