# Why can not I use two foreign key in one table?

Tags: sql

I try to write it:

```
CREATE TABLE Man
(
    ID NUMERIC(9) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Woman
(
    ID NUMERIC(9) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE MotherOf
(
    MID NUMERIC(9),
    FID NUMERIC(9)
    PRIMARY KEY(MID, FID)
    FOREIGN KEY (MID) REFERENCES Woman(ID)
    FOREIGN KEY (FID) REFERENCES Man(ID)
)
```

and I get this error:

> Multiple FOREIGNKEY constrains were specified for columns 'FID', table 'MotherOf'.

Why can't I do this?

Comment: Of *COURSE* you can have two foreign keys in one table!  You're just missing  commas (",") between your constraints!  Look here: [Create table syntax diagram](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-create-table-syntax-diagrams/)

Comment: This was the first result I found when I searched SO with your error message: [You are missing commas.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48683042/2430549)

Answer (score 1):

Try it with it looking like:

```
CREATE TABLE MotherOf(
    MID NUMERIC(9) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Woman(ID),
    FID NUMERIC(9) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Man(ID)
    PRIMARY KEY(MID, FID)
)
```